# Get the avaliable XPaths of an Html page?

Tags: html, .net, xml, vb.net, xpath

I've taken and adapted [this](http://bytes.com/topic/xml/answers/889001-all-available-xpath-xml-document) code of how to retrieve the XPath expressions of an XML document.

I Would like to do the same but using an html page to retrieve its avaliable XPaths ( maybe an `HtmlDocument`? ), is this possibly?

Note: I can accept a native solution or else using [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) library.

This is the XML method:

```
''' <summary>
''' Gets all the XPath expressions of an XML Document.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="Document">Indicates the XML document.</param>
''' <returns>List(Of System.String).</returns>
Public Function GetXPaths(ByVal Document As Xml.XmlDocument) As List(Of String)

    Dim XPathList As New List(Of String)

    Dim XPath As String = String.Empty

    For Each Child As Xml.XmlNode In Document.ChildNodes

        If Child.NodeType = Xml.XmlNodeType.Element Then
            GetXPaths(Child, XPathList, XPath)
        End If

    Next ' child

    Return XPathList

End Function

''' <summary>
''' Gets all the XPath expressions of an XML Node.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="Node">Indicates the XML node.</param>
''' <param name="XPathList">Indicates a ByReffered XPath list as a <see cref="List(Of String)"/>.</param>
''' <param name="XPath">Indicates the current XPath.</param>
Private Sub GetXPaths(ByVal Node As Xml.XmlNode,
                      ByRef XPathList As List(Of String),
                      Optional ByVal XPath As String = Nothing)

    XPath &= "/" & Node.Name

    If Not XPathList.Contains(XPath) Then
        XPathList.Add(XPath)
    End If

    For Each Child As Xml.XmlNode In Node.ChildNodes

        If Child.NodeType = Xml.XmlNodeType.Element Then
            GetXPaths(Child, XPathList, XPath)
        End If

    Next ' child

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, HtmlAgilityPack has a very similar class structures to `XmlDocument`. So I believe you can easiliy adapt current solution to cope with `HtmlDocument`, something like this :

```
Public Function GetXPaths(ByVal Document As HtmlDocument) As List(Of String)
    Dim XPathList As New List(Of String)
    Dim XPath As String = String.Empty
    For Each Child As HtmlNode In Document.DocumentNode.ChildNodes
        If Child.NodeType = HtmlNodeType.Element Then
            GetXPaths(Child, XPathList, XPath)
        End If
    Next ' child'
    Return XPathList
End Function

Private Sub GetXPaths(ByVal Node As HtmlNode,
                  ByRef XPathList As List(Of String),
                  Optional ByVal XPath As String = Nothing)
    XPath &= "/" & Node.Name
    If Not XPathList.Contains(XPath) Then
        XPathList.Add(XPath)
    End If
    For Each Child As HtmlNode In Node.ChildNodes
        If Child.NodeType = HtmlNodeType.Element Then
            GetXPaths(Child, XPathList, XPath)
        End If
    Next ' child'
End Sub
```

Worked fine when tested using HTML that is XML compliant. But I can't guarantee about how far this will work against malformed HTML documents.